# strange behavior when using recursion in ksh93

Tags: ksh, pdksh

I'm facing some problems in ksh93, when going through directories recursively.

create some files and directories.

```
base=/tmp/nonsens

for i in {1..3}
do
    mkdir -p ${base}/dir${i}
    for j in {1..2}
    do
        mkdir ${base}/dir${i}/dir${j}
        touch ${base}/dir${i}/dir${j}/file${j}
        touch ${base}/dir${i}/file${j}
    done
done
```

Now going through it with a ksh93 script.

```
rdir ()
{
    typeset dir=$1

    for file in `ls $dir`
    do
        if [ -d $dir/$file ]
        then
            echo "Directory: $dir/$file"
            rdir $dir/$file
        else
            echo "File     : $dir/$file"
        fi
    done
}   

rdir /tmp/nonsens
```

will create this output in ksh93

```
cheko@chwiclu1:~> rdir /tmp/nonsens
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir1
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/file1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/dir2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/file1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/file2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/dir2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/dir3
```

while using pdksh/bash will create this

```
cheko@redcube:~$ rdir /tmp/nonsens
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir1
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir1/file1
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/dir2/file2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/file1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir1/file2
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir2
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir2/dir1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir2/dir1/file1
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir2/dir2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir2/dir2/file2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir2/file1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir2/file2
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir3
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir3/dir1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir3/dir1/file1
Directory: /tmp/nonsens/dir3/dir2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir3/dir2/file2
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir3/file1
File     : /tmp/nonsens/dir3/file2
```

Does someone know a workaround? Or does a switch exists that makes ksh93 behave as it should?

Answer (score 3):

I followed a thought on this -- and had the right idea but the wrong reason. pdksh follows ksh88 semantics, and a quick google reveals that there are differences between ksh88 and ksh93 when functions are defined.

[This FAQ for ksh93](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html) states in Part III (Shell Scripting):

> Q18. What is the difference between function name and name()?
>
> A18. In ksh88 these were the same.
> However, the POSIX standard choose
> foo() for functions and defined System
> V Release 2 semantics to them so that
> there are no local variables and so
> that traps are not scoped.  ksh93
> keeps the ksh88 semantics for
> functions defined as function name,
> and has changed the name() semantics
> to match the POSIX semantics. Clearly,
> function name is more useful.

I don't have access to a ksh93 shell to test this, but the implication is that when you call the rdir function from within itself, the variable `dir` is getting overwritten. So based on the above, try declaring your function as `function rdir` to get ksh88 semantics with locally scoped variables.

Answer (score 1):

perfect!

```
function rdir
{
    typeset dir=$1

    for file in `ls $dir`
    do
        if [ -d $dir/$file ]
        then
            echo "Directory: $dir/$file"
            rdir $dir/$file
        else
            echo "File     : $dir/$file"
        fi
    done
}

rdir /tmp/nonsens
```

does the job. Thank you.